# "invalid factor level, NA generated" error when trying to link colour information in with subgroup

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to link my data frame to color by doing this. However, I keep on receiving

> "Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, pca_matrix[, "Subgroup"] == 1, value = c(1L,  :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated"

```
samples_names <- row.names(PCA_Model$rotation)
# Bind sample names to their subgroup
pca_matrix <- cbind(samples_names, "Subgroup"=labeled_subgroup, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Link dataframe to color
pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"][pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"]==1] <- "blue"
pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"][pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"]==2] <- "red"
pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"][pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"]==3] <- "yellow"
pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"][pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"]==4] <- "green"
pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"][pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"]==5] <- "black"
pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"][pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"]==6] <- "white"
```

I have read other questions online saying it was because my character variable was becoming a factor and I should use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` flag when making your data frame to force `"Type"` to be a character.

My data frame looks like this and contains subgroups C1 - C6. I want to link the subgroups to a color so I can plot my data as a 3d plot and use the color information to differentiate between groups.

[image]

Comment: The image shows value C1 instead of 1, in 'subgroup', column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this one by one, an option is `factor`

```
factor(pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"], levels = paste0("C", 1:6), 
      labels = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green", "black", "white"))
```

Comment: When I run this, it seems to produce 
TCGA.DJ.A2QB.THCA.C3_ TCGA.DJ.A3UQ.THCA.C3_ TCGA.DJ.A4UT.THCA.C3_ TCGA.DJ.A4V4.THCA.C3_ TCGA.DV.A4VZ.KIRC.C3_ 
                 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>

Comment: @EdwardMuldrew  Do you have other values 'Subgroup', in addition to 1:6

Comment: @EdwardMuldrew   Your image shows the  'Subgroup' values as 'C1', 'C2', etc. but in your code it is 1:6.  I updated the code

Comment: Sorry I used your edited version there and it worked perfectly, thanks! 
My only other question is when I am trying to use this in plot3d. 

I do this
colours <- factor(pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"], levels = paste0("C", 1:6),labels = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green", "black", "white"))
plot3d(PCA_Model$x[,1:3], col=colours)

But only red and blue are shown, would you know why this would be?

Comment: @EdwardMuldrew  Can you wrap with `as.character(factor(..`